# LRU cache in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.x, cache

Here is my simple code for LRU cache in Python 2.7. Appreciate if anyone could review for logic correctness and also potential performance improvements.

A confusion want to ask for advice is, I am using a `list` to track access time, the first element of the list the is least time accessed, and the last element is the most recent accessed element. And I am using `remove` method of `list`, for example, statement `accessQueue.remove(key)`, wondering what is the time complexity of `list.remove`, is it linear or log(N)?

```
from collections import defaultdict
kvStore = defaultdict(str)
accessQueue = []
maxSize = 10

def cacheSet(key, value):
        kvStore[key] = value
        if key in accessQueue:
            accessQueue.remove(key)
            accessQueue.append(key)
        else:
            accessQueue.append(key)
        if len(accessQueue) > maxSize:
            accessQueue.pop(0)
def cacheGet(key):
    if key in kvStore:
        accessQueue.remove(key)
        accessQueue.append(key)
        return kvStore[key]
    else:
        return None
def cachePrint():
    for k,v in kvStore.items():
        print k,v

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for i in range(10):
        cacheSet(i, "value " + str(i))
    for i in range(10):
        print cacheGet(i)

    cacheSet(11, "value " + str(11))
    cachePrint()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should be a class - this is what OOP exists to do, abstract away details like this and contain them all in an object.  You'll want to subclass `collections.MutableMapping`.  You can also use an ordered dict to combine the lru behavior with the normal dict behavior.  Below is my class implementation. I've left out a lot of the details, but most of the methods you can just delegate to the internal ordered dict `self.store`.  You'll probably want to make sure you implement all of the dict methods, which you can find [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=dict#dict).

```
from collections import MutableMapping, OrderedDict

class LruCache(MutableMapping):

    def __init__(self, max_size=10, *args, **kwargs):
        self.max_size = max_size
        self.store = OrderedDict()
        self.update(dict(*args, **kwargs))

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        # Move the key to the end of the cache
        try:
            self.store[key] = self.store.pop(key)
            return self.store[key]
        except KeyError:
            if not hasattr(self, '__missing__'):
                raise
            else:
                return self.__missing__(key)

    def get(self, key, default=None):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:
            return default

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        try:
            self.store.pop(key)
        except KeyError:
            # We just want to move it to the back, so ignore it
            pass

        self.store[key] = value

        while len(self) > self.max_size:
            self.store.popitem(last=False)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        del self.store[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.store)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.store)
```

Comment: Thanks Dannnno, vote up. Your code is much better. Wondering what is the time complexity for adding element (your code of `self.store[key] = value`) and remove element (your code of `self.store.popitem(last=False)`)?

Comment: BTW, also for my original implementation, what is the time complexity of `list.remove` by a given value, it is O(n) or O(logN)? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dannnno, if you could comment on my above questions, it will be great. :)

Comment: @LinMa No clue. Those are things you could find out by reading the documentation or looking at the source code. I would assume that most of those are not guaranteed by the language, and could vary across Python implementation

Comment: @Dannnno Can you please add some test cases as well?

Comment: @girish no, I won't be adding any test cases; I have neither the time nor the interest. If you find a problem with my implementation feel free to let me know and I may make updates then